# What are all special characters in R and how are they deparsed?

Tags: r

Some special characters can be specified by escaping them with "\" in strings.

Which are they and how are they rendered when printing or using `deparse()` on them ?

Answer (score 5):

These characters are referenced in https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Literal-constants

Copied from there and altered for formatting:

- `\'` single quote
- `\"` double quote
- `\n` newline (aka ‘line feed’, LF)
- `\r` carriage return (CR)
- `\t` tab character
- `\b` backspace
- `\a` bell
- `\f` form feed
- `\v` vertical tab
- `\\` backslash itself
- `\nnn` character with given octal code – sequences of one, two or three digits in the range 0 ... 7 are accepted.
- `\xnn` character with given hex code – sequences of one or two hex digits (with entries 0 ... 9 A ... F a ... f).
- `\unnnn` `\u{nnnn}` (where multibyte locales are supported, otherwise an error). Unicode character with given hex code – sequences of up to four hex digits. The character needs to be valid in the current locale.
- `\Unnnnnnnn \U{nnnnnnnn}` (where multibyte locales are supported, otherwise an error). Unicode character with given hex code – sequences of up to eight hex digits.

When printing a character vector, double quotes are used to contain the string so single quotes are not escaped as they don't need to so they might not be considered special in most cases.

`\"` to `\\` print as defined above, with double quotes.

When deparsing those the backslashes and double quotes are escaped by an extra backslash.

```r
"'"
#> [1] "'"
deparse("'")
#> [1] "\"'\""
"\a"
#> [1] "\a"
deparse("\a")
#> [1] "\"\\a\""
```

`\nnn`, `\xnn`, `\unnnn`, `\Unnnnnnnn` are a bit different because they're different ways of showing the same things (with different limitations).

When a unicode character or emoji is available it is used :

```r
"\101"             
#> [1] "A"
"\x41"         
#> [1] "A"
"\u0041"    
#> [1] "A"
"\U0000041"
#> [1] "A"
"\U001F436"
#> [1] ""
```

Otherwise depending on the code point range (the code point value is given by `i <- utf8ToInt(x)`) different notations are used:

- 1 to 6: `"\00n"`
- 7 to 13: `"\a"`, `"\b"`, `"\t"`, `"\n"`, `"\v"`, `"\f"`, `"\r"`
- 14 to 31: `"\0nn"`
- 32 to 126: ASCII characters
- 127: "\127"
- 128 to 159: `"\u00nn"`
- 160 to 255: latin characters
- 256 (16^2) to 65535: unicode characters or code points represented as `"\unnnn"`
- 65536 (16^4) to 4294967295 (16^8 - 1) : unicode characters or code points represented as `"\U{nnnnnnnn}"` (with curly braces)

For the 2 last items note that the doc above says

> where multibyte locales are supported, otherwise an error.

On my MacBook Pro I cannot go up to 8 hex digits with the `"\U{nnnn}"` notation, my max is 5 digits (16^5 - 1 = 1048575) and they're displayed as "\U{0nnnnn}" (6 digits starting with a null), above that I get:

> Error: invalid \U{xxxxxxxx} value ...

We still need to talk about "\xnn", as we've seen above `deparse()` doesn't use it on valid code points, however we can find it in irregular strings, which might be a bug and might be system dependent.

On my system `\xnn` works as advertised until code point 127 (`"\x7f"`), then it outputs some `\xnn` strings that have no associated code point. I also notice that when using negative numbers in `intToUtf8()` the deparsed string will contain a sequence of "\xn"

```r
"\x7e"
#> [1] "~"
"\x7f"
#> [1] "\177"
"\x80"
#> [1] "\x80"
utf8ToInt("\x80")
#> [1] NA
nchar("\x80")
#> Error in nchar("\x80"): invalid multibyte string, element 1
intToUtf8(-1)
#> [1] "\xff\xbf\xbf\xbf\xbf"
```

Here's some code to play around with :

```r
codepoints <- 120:130
codepoints_hex <- structure(c(codepoints),  class = "hexmode")
x <- sapply(parse(text = sprintf("'\\U%s'", codepoints_hex)), deparse)
writeLines(sprintf("%s: %s", codepoints, x))
#> 120: "x"
#> 121: "y"
#> 122: "z"
#> 123: "{"
#> 124: "|"
#> 125: "}"
#> 126: "~"
#> 127: "\177"
#> 128: "\u0080"
#> 129: "\u0081"
#> 130: "\u0082"

y <- sapply(parse(text = sprintf("'\\x%s'", codepoints_hex)), deparse)
writeLines(sprintf("%s: %s", codepoints, y))
#> 120: "x"
#> 121: "y"
#> 122: "z"
#> 123: "{"
#> 124: "|"
#> 125: "}"
#> 126: "~"
#> 127: "\177"
#> 128: "\x80"
#> 129: "\x81"
#> 130: "\x82"
```

Comment: One exception:  `"\0"` is not allowed: `Error: nul character not allowed`.  Similarly for other representations of a nul like `\00`, `\x00` etc.  The parser also accepts `"\\`"` and `"\ "`, but the deparser doesn't escape those.

Comment: One more:  a backslash followed by an actual newline is accepted, and deparsed as `\n`.